# SQL Triggers to duplicate update changes to another table

Tags: sql, triggers, backup

So I have an intermitant problem that I need a temporary fix for.

(something is causing issues with two tables intermittently (every 3-4 weeks))

One table gets completly cleared out and another seems to have individual records removed...

as this is an ongoing issue we are still investigating the main cause but need a temporary fix.

As such I have setup a second "Backup" table for each of these tables and am trying to setup triggers to copy ALL Insert and Update commands

I have created the Insert triggers with no problem.

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[MainInsertBackup] 
On [dbo].[tblMain] AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tblMainBackup 
    SELECT * FROM inserted 
END
```

now I need a trigger that does the same for updates (performs the updates on the tblMainBackup).

this way I should ensure that the backup table has all of the information from the main but if a record is removed somehow it can be copied back to the main table from the backup table.

Only examples I have found perform updates in individual fields on the update, or insert a whole new record on the update into a log table.

any help is apriciated.

Comment: Which dbms? (This doesn't look like ANSI SQL syntax...)

Comment: What's the purpose of the backup table? Is it just to store the very latest revision of the non-deleted data or to log all changes - given that you have mystery removals, are you sure you don't have mystery updates to undo also?

Comment: The purpose is to store the latest revision of the non deleted data.

The issue appears to be the records being completely removed... there shouldn't be an update issue as the table updates are performed by being linked to an access front end form....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this UPDATE trigger to update the rows in tblMainbackup while update row in tblMain table

```
CREATE Trigger [dbo].[MainUpdateBackup] 
On [dbo].[tblMain] AFTER UPDATE AS 
BEGIN     
    UPDATE tblMainbackup
    SET tblMainbackup.col1 = i1.col1,
        tblMainbackup.col2 = i1.col2,
        tblMainbackup.col3 = i1.col3    
    FROM tblMainbackup t1
          INNER JOIN inserted i1
          ON t1.Id = i1.ID
END
```

Comment: this looks like what I need, however is there a way to state update all columns as in a similar syntax to the insert 

Insert * FROM Inserted

or do I need to setup each column in the trigger individually?

Comment: need to setup each column individually. update syntax don't have that feature